# FabricJS gradient color values

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I was trying gradient color with difefrent shapes and values in fabricJS, what I came across is for linear one with values `(x1,y1,x2,y2)` if we do`(10,0,0,0)` and `colorStops={0:'red',1:'black'}` it starts with left side taking black color and applying gradient. But if I want to start from right side of a shape so either I can `(0,0,10,0)` or `colorStops={0:'black',1:'red'}`[switch the color], but value(gradient range) does not comes out to be same.

For value 10 for x1 the area it covers is more than if we do x2 = 10.
How can I manage equal gradient range for`(top,right,bottom,left)`?

PS: for right side I tried to give maximum value say 150% more that the side of the shape to `x2` by keeping color order same.
here is my working fiddle [fiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/monis/vtvdcnp5/7/) and fiddle 2 on changing the color order [fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/monis/vtvdcnp5/8/)

Answer (score 0):

The point is that x1,x2,y1,y2 are not top,left,bottom,margin.

Are 2 points p1 and p2, and their respective coordinates

```
p1 = { x1, y1 }, p2 = { x2, y2 }.
```

They describe to points that define a segment where the gradient lives on.

First thing you have to understand is that a linear gradient extend infinitely in one direction, the direction where the color does not change.

So you cannot give it 4 margins and expect it to have them like a frame.

If you take a fabric shape, a rect, that has width 100 and height 50, you can define a linear horizontal gradient that has 10 pixel margin left and right, in this way:

```
x1: 10
x2: WIDTH - 10
y1: any number
y2: the same number as y1.
```

This will make the gradient travel from 10 to 90 and having the first and last 10 pixel of the start/end color. Whatever is the color order.

If you want a vertical one:

```
x1: any number
x2: the same number as x2.
y1: 10
y2: HEIGHT - 10
```

If you use different numbers for all the coordinates, the gradient will get an angle and will not be aligned with width or height.